# Passing a form name to a variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can someone tell me how to pass a form name to a function that executes a command?

I have a navigation strip that is identical on 6 forms. When someone clicks a button on the strip, the same command (to either enable or disable buttons on the strip) is executed regardless of the form.

What I am trying to do is create a function that can handle the buttons on all of the forms.

For Example: This is a calling statement when the edit button is clicked:

```
 Private Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdEdit.Click
     'Edit Record - Button 6
     'Stop
     Dim OK As Boolean
     IsEditing = True

     OK = Button_Edit("Creditors")
     'OK = Button_Edit(Creditors) - fail

 End Sub
```

This is the function called:

```
Public Function Button_Edit(ByRef FrmName As Form) As Boolean
    Stop
    'With FrmName
    FrmName.Controls("cmdFirst").Enabled = False
    FrmName.Controls("cmdPrevious").Enabled = False
    FrmName.Controls("cmdNext").Enabled = False
    FrmName.Controls("cmdLast").Enabled = False

    FrmName.Controls("cmdSearch").Enabled = False

    FrmName.Controls("cmdEdit").Enabled = False
    FrmName.Controls("cmdAdd").Enabled = False

    FrmName.Controls("cmdDelete").Enabled = False

    FrmName.Controls("cmdSave").Enabled = True
    FrmName.Controls("cmdReject").Enabled = True

    FrmName.Controls("cmdReports").Enabled = False

    FrmName.Controls("cmdPrint").Enabled = False
    FrmName.Controls("cmdExit").Enabled = True
    'End With
    Return True
End Function
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I have tried just about everything I can find on the net to no avail.

Comment: few ways to do it. you can raise events in your strip and listen to them in the form. Or make your form implement interface, pass it to the strip, and then in the strip call interface methods

Comment: Is the code supposed to work with the current form, or does it modify a different form? Is there ever only ONE instance of each form type open at a time? We need more details to make the code useful.

Comment: It works (supposed to) with the current form on display. Only one form at a time is displayed. The navigation control containing the buttons is identical across all forms. The function is the same regardless of which form is being displayed.

Comment: @MGC If you only have one form open, and the navigation bar code repeats in every form I don't know why you're passing the form name around. Just literally set all your controls `cmdFirst.Enabled = False`, etc. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like you're going about this the wrong way. One option is to create a single form with all the `Buttons` and put the code there, then have all your other forms inherit that instead of `Form`. Another option is to create a user control containing all the `Buttons` and put the code there, then add that user control to each form. VB is an OO language so write OO code.

Comment: Why would you have a parameter of type `Form` and call it `FrmName`? Based on the type and the way it's used, it's obviously the form itself, not the name of the form. Why do you think you can pass a `String` as an argument when a `Form` is expected? It seems clear that what you actually want to pass is the current form. How do you usually refer to the current object in code? If you don't already know, it's pretty easy to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit flaky, but a `UserControl` is probably what you are after.

Add a `UserControl` to your project. This will look like a borderless form. Add your buttons to the UserControl (I've added four in my example - `cmdEdit`, `cmdPrevious`, `cmdNext`, `cmdSave`). Then add your Enable/Disable code. Also declare some `Events` - these will be handled in the hosting form. See "**UserControl1 Code**", below.

*NOW BUILD YOUR PROJECT* - this will then make `UserControl1` available in your toolbox.

Then you can drag your `UserControl1` from the toolbox to `Form1`. In your form, you then can handle the UserControl1 events to do your form-specific stuff. See "**Form1 code**" below.

You might find it easier to put the UserControl into a DLL and reference that, rather than mingle it with your main code. REMEMBER: you need to **build** the UserControl before its events etc. are updated in the IDE!

---

**UserControl1 code**

```
Public Class UserControl1
  Public Event EditClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Public Event PreviousClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Public Event NextClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Public Event SaveClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    cmdPrevious.Enabled = True
    cmdNext.Enabled = True
    cmdSave.Enabled = False
  End Sub
  Private Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdEdit.Click
    cmdEdit.Enabled = False
    cmdPrevious.Enabled = False
    cmdNext.Enabled = False
    cmdSave.Enabled = True
    RaiseEvent EditClick(sender, e)
  End Sub

  Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPrevious.Click
    cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    cmdPrevious.Enabled = True
    cmdNext.Enabled = True
    cmdSave.Enabled = False
    RaiseEvent PreviousClick(sender, e)
  End Sub

  Private Sub cmdNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
    cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    cmdPrevious.Enabled = True
    cmdNext.Enabled = True
    cmdSave.Enabled = False
    RaiseEvent NextClick(sender, e)
  End Sub

  Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    cmdPrevious.Enabled = True
    cmdNext.Enabled = True
    cmdSave.Enabled = False
    RaiseEvent SaveClick(sender, e)
  End Sub

End Class
```

**Form1 code**

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub UserControl11_EditClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.EditClick
    MessageBox.Show("Editing")
  End Sub

  Private Sub UserControl11_NextClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.NextClick
    MessageBox.Show("Next")
  End Sub

  Private Sub UserControl11_PreviousClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.PreviousClick
    MessageBox.Show("Previous")
  End Sub

  Private Sub UserControl11_SaveClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.SaveClick
    MessageBox.Show("Record saved")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo code, how to do it via interface

```vb
interface IClicks
    sub Help()
    sub OK()
    sub cancel()
end interface

class Form1 implements IClicks
   

    sub Help()
        ' call help
    end sub
    sub OK()
        ' call ok
    end sub
    sub cancel()
       ' call cancel
    end sub
end interface

class Strip inherits StripControl
   
    
    sub ButtonHelp_OnClick(....)
        dim f as IClicks = DirectCast(FindForm(), Iclicks)
        f.Help()
    end sub

    sub ButtonOk_OnClick(....)
        dim f as IClicks = DirectCast(FindForm(), Iclicks)
        f.OK()
    end subend interface


    sub ButtonCancel_onClick(....)
        dim f as IClicks = DirectCast(FindForm(), Iclicks)
        f.Cancel()
    end sub

end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tag value to your toolstrip buttons, 0 for Save and Reject, 1 for the others. Then pass your toolstrip to a module function and set the Enabled property of each button there.

```
' module Sub
Public Sub EnableDisableButtons(ts As ToolStrip, enable As Boolean)
    For Each ctrl In ts.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is ToolStripButton Then
            If ctrl.tag = 1 Then    '   other buttons
                CType(ctrl, ToolStripButton).Enabled = enable
            Else    '   save & reject buttons
                CType(ctrl, ToolStripButton).Enabled = Not enable
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

In the click event of one of your ToolStripButton, call

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdEdit.Click
    ' False = Save and Reject will be enabled, others will be disabled
    EnableDisableButtons(<name of toolstrip in form>, False)
    
End Sub
```